# Can a Ruby method know it's name?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to know the name of the method currently run in Ruby?

**EDIT**

For example I can use `self` to get the current class.  Is there a way to get the current method that is running?  Is there a 'magic method' that can do the following?

```
def method1
    p "this method's name is " + magicmethod # => this method's name is method1
end
```

Comment: clarify your question is please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `__method__`:

```
class Test
  def testing
    __method__
  end
end
```

Note that `__method__` is a `Symbol` and not a `String`

This requires at least Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu sorry, I meant 'requires at least'. Clarified it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How the below: :)

```
p RUBY_VERSION

module Kernel
private
    def method_name
      caller[0] =~ /`([^']*)'/ and $1
    end
end

class Foo
  def test_method
    method_name
  end
end

puts Foo.new.test_method
```

*Output:*

```
"1.9.3"
test_method
```

Comment: What is the point of this if you have to actually write the method's name to get its name?

Comment: I mean, `def testing; method(:testing).name; end` is equal to `def testing; :testing; end`.

Comment: @LBg tell me please if it is good or you want any more improvement.

Comment: It's ok now. It implements `__method__` using pure ruby.

Comment: I really don't like to upvote people who are begging upvotes.